# Android Studio - ¿Como hago para desplazar vistas programáticamente?

Tags: android, android-studio, design

**Representación gráfica de mi layout**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imágen lo dice casi todo. Lo que quiero es que al tocar el **Button 1** desaparezcan las vistas **"B"** y que las vistas **"C"** se desplazen hacia arriba quedando como **quiero que quede**. Al tocar el **Button 2 y Button 3** no va a pasar nada, es decir que las vistas **"B"** se mantendrán en su posición.

**Lo que intenté:**

Intenté simplemente haciendo desaparecer las vistas **"B"** con View.INVISIBLE, pero solamente desaparecen y el espacio que ocupaban en el layout se conserva. Por lo que mi layout se termina viendo **"Como queda :C"**

Realmente no tengo ni idea de que se puede hacer para resolver esto, por lo que agradecería mucho su ayuda.

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: reemplaza el invisible por gone

Comment: jajjajaja, tremendo. No puedo creer que era tan simple. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres desaparecer una vista usa el mètodo [setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) , pero tienes dos opciones, usar [`View.INVISIBLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE):

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Esto provocara que la vista desaparezca pero continuara ocupando el espacio.

la otra opciòn es usar **[`View.GONE`](http://GONE)**:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Usar [`View.GONE`](http://GONE), provocara que la vista desaparezca pero no ocupara el espacio**, en realidad esto es lo que necesitas aplicándolo a tu `TextView`, de esta forma desaparecerá la vista pero no continuara ocupando el espacio :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]